# Do two L4 ports perform better than one port?

Tags: performance, gateway, http-proxy

I have a micro-service HTTP backend, which used Nginx as gateway. I have two domain names for clients: `mydomain1.com` and `mydomain2.com`.

client ---> Nginx ---> backend

Now, I must decide which ports should the Nginx listen. It seems that I could use two ports (each domain has its own port) or only one port (two domains share one port).

In a word, I have to choose the solution between

```
http://mydomain1.com:2222
http://mydomain2.com:2222
```

and

```
http://mydomain1.com:2222
http://mydomain2.com:3333
```

Which one is better?

Comment: better at what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transport-layer port? As long as the same physical interface is used it doesn't matter one bit.